# Returning SQL LIKE & GROUP BY results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty simple table in a database with 3 columns called `people`. Example:

```
user           id             notes
john           01             has red hair, last logged in 02/04/12
tony           02             has brown hair, last logged in 04/03/12
brian          03             has brown hair, last logged in 03/06/13
amanda         04             has blonde hair, last logged in 05/07/14
…
```

if I want to group by the notes field, and do a count, the 2nd and 3rd rows show as a count of 1 each because the logged in date is different; what I would like to do is chop off the date and amalgamate and count purely by hair colour, e.g. if I run a query:

```
SELECT `notes`, COUNT( `user` ) AS Count 
FROM `people` 
WHERE `notes` LIKE "%hair%" GROUP BY `notes`;
```

I get a result of:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-------+
|notes                                    | Count |
+-----------------------------------------+-------+
|has red hair, last logged in 02/04/12    |      1|
|has brown hair, last logged in 04/03/12  |      1|
|has brown hair, last logged in 03/06/13  |      1|
|has blonde hair, last logged in 05/07/14 |      1|
+-----------------------------------------+-------+
```

would like to achieve a result of:

```
+-------------------+------+
|notes              |Count | 
+-------------------+------+
|has red hair       |     1|
|has brown hair     |     2|
|has blonde hair    |     1|
+-------------------+------+
```

Is this at all possible?

Cheers.

Comment: Start normalizing your database first! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Can I ask why you have these dates in the notes field?

Comment: Certainly - the data has been anonymised (obvs) and the actual data set is from the output of a tool I couldn't really control and an XML import into the DB. The notes field has very similar text, but all 'different' due to times and dates.

Comment: Will check out normalisation, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, ',', 1), COUNT( `user` ) AS Count
FROM `people`
WHERE `notes` LIKE "%hair%"
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`notes`, ',', 1)
```

Of course this is a somewhat dirty workaround. A better approach would be to separate out the hair color, but I realize that this may not always be possible.

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/418bd/2)

Comment: This looks very helpful. As ever though, there is a complication, and not every entry in the notes field uses a comma as a separator. Sometimes it's not entirely obvious what I could use. This has, however, given me something to work on. Even if you think that it's an ugly hack, I think that this may be the way forward. Am also going to look at normalisation too. I will check back later :)

Comment: Sorry, just to add, this is a gift that keeps on giving (with suitable edits). It delivers!